# Insufficient Storage error on install packages

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i install flutter packages then i this get error

```
Flutter Error Package install error: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86 64
```

[Here his a screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M218b.png)
I have large amount of space in my pc

Comment: what did you try until now? it looks like there is an answer here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8824#issuecomment-407970690

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use to have the same error and you need space on your phone not on your machine , if you are using emulator reinstall your virtual machine.